# Are Laguerre-Gaussian functions compactly supported?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

Laguerre-Gaussian functions are very common in optics and I wonder if they are Compactly Supported. These functions are essentially an associated Laguerre Polynomial modulated by a gaussian function.

Also if someone would please recommend some good bibliography on the subject because coleagues seem to misuse the term.

Comment: Presumably you are interested in [these functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Laguerre-Gaussian_modes). I would answer "NO". They are not compactly supported, because to have compact support means that the function is exactly zero outside some ball.  Those functions do quickly approach zero outside the beam width, but they don't beome exactly zero. Even the $TEM_{00}$ has fuzzy edges. Furthermore, the functions have significant values far away along the axis. It may be that people discussing compact support ignore the axial direction. IDK, that is just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laguerre-Gaussian functions, as Jyrki notes, are not compactly supported.  Rather, the Laguerre polynomials form an orthogonal basis over the Hilbert space $L^2(0,\infty)$ having inner product

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\infty} dx \, f(x)\, g(x)\, e^{-x}$$

In optical beam profiles, you are not going to find many good representations of functions with finite support, except as an infinite sum over functions like Laguerre Gaussians that are not finitely supported.

Nonetheless, if you want a reference that treats Laguerre polynomials with all due respect, I recommend the book my professor Sam Holland wrote on Hilbert space for undergraduates: *[Applied Analysis by the Hilbert Space Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486458016)*.